# ROS service with bool as request and bool as response

Tags: ros, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't want to use std_srvs::SetBoolRequest or any stuff from mavros. I just want to use bare boolean. My callback function would be :

```
bool Command::arming_service(bool request, bool response) {
   // whatever 
   return false;
}
```

How can I do that ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356492/ros-service-with-bool-as-request-and-bool-as-response/) by [maxime](https://answers.ros.org/users/55264/maxime/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2020-07-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can't if you intend to use a ROS service. This is how services are designed.

You can create your own service type, if you want, only containing booleans.

`my_pkg/MyBoolSrv`:

```
bool input
---
bool output
```

But you'll still have the respective function signature as

```
bool Command::arming_service(my_pkg::MyBoolSrv::Request request, my_pkg::MyBoolSrv::Response response) {
   // whatever with request.input and response.output
   return false;
}
```

If this doesn't answer your question, please provide more details on your use case and what you actually want to do.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2020-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [maxime](https://answers.ros.org/users/55264/maxime/) on 2020-07-06**:
It does perfectly answer it, thank you :)

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2020-07-07**:
Happy to help!